# Creating Curved Text with SVG and JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create curved text in SVG using Javascript. I have faced a lot of problems, specially the namespace related ones, but now everything works, a path and a circle are successfully shown, but the text is not displayed. When I copy-paste the created svg code in browser inspector and add that to the svg, it works as intended. But I can't make it work using JS. The whole code is as you can see:

```
<html>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div id="svgbox"></div>
</body>

<script>
var svg;
var last_shape; // for debug 


function qs(sel)
{
    return document.querySelector(sel);
}


function SVG(el)
{
    this.element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    qs(el).appendChild(this.element);

    var props = {   
                    "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                    "xmlns:xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
                    "version": "1.1",
                    "style": "width:100%;height:100%;",
                    "stroke": "#58b",
                    "fill":"none",
                    "stroke-width": "2"
                };

    for (i in props) {
        this.element.setAttribute(i, props[i]);
    }

    this.create = function(tag,props) {
        var o = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);

        if(typeof(props)!="undefined") {
            for (i in props) {
                o.setAttribute(i, props[i]);
            }
        }

        return o;

    }

    this.add = function(tag,props) {
        var o = this.create(tag,props);

        this.element.appendChild( o ); 
        return o;
    };

    this.addTo = function(parent, tag, props) {
        var o = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);

        if(typeof(props)!="undefined") {
            for (i in props) {
                o.setAttribute(i, props[i]);
            }
        }

        parent.appendChild(o);

        return o;

    };

    return this;
}



function drawArc(svg, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, controlX, controlY, props)
{
    var o = svg.add( "path",    {
                            "d":"M" + fromX + " " + fromY + " Q " +
                                    controlX + " " + controlY + " " +
                                    toX + " " + toY
                        });

    if(typeof(props)!="undefined") {
        for (i in props) {
            o.setAttribute(i, props[i]);
        }
    }
    last_shape = o;

    return o;
}

function drawLabeledArrow(svg, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, title, props)
{
    var arc_id = "arc-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000);
    var arc = drawArc( svg, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, (fromX+toX)/2, (fromY+toY)/2 - (fromX+toX)/2, {id: arc_id});
    var head_base_x = arc.getPointAtLength(arc.getTotalLength() - 4).x;
    var head_base_y = arc.getPointAtLength(arc.getTotalLength() - 4).y;


    last_shape = svg.add("text");   
    last_shape = svg.addTo(last_shape, "textPath", {"fill":"#ff0000", "xlink:href":"#"+arc_id});    
    last_shape.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));

    last_shape = svg.add( "circle",     {
                                                    cx: head_base_x,
                                                    cy: head_base_y,
                                                    r: 4,
                                                    fill: "#5ad"
                                                });


}



function onLoad() 
{
    svg = SVG('#svgbox');

    drawLabeledArrow(svg, 10,100, 200, 100, "test label");
}
</script>

</html>
```

I'd appreciate if anyone tells me what's wrong here, and if there is any good and short explanation of all these problems in working with SVG in JS. Thanks.

---

UPDATE: I modified the code to use setAttributeNS instead, but still no success.

```
function drawLabeledArrow(svg, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, title, props)
{
    var arc_id = "arc-"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000);
    var arc = drawArc( svg, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, (fromX+toX)/2, (fromY+toY)/2 - (fromX+toX)/2, {id: arc_id});
    var head_base_x = arc.getPointAtLength(arc.getTotalLength() - 4).x;
    var head_base_y = arc.getPointAtLength(arc.getTotalLength() - 4).y;


    last_shape = svg.add("text");   


    var o = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "textPath");

    o.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "xlink:href", "#"+arc_id);
    o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));

    last_shape.appendChild( o ); 



    last_shape = svg.add( "circle",     {
                                                    cx: head_base_x,
                                                    cy: head_base_y,
                                                    r: 4,
                                                    fill: "#5ad"
                                                });


}
```

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I updated the code, but output didn't change. I added the new code to the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, that was a careless mistake. Thanks. It is solved. Would you please submit this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xlink:href attribute cannot be set with setAttribute as that method can only set attributes in the null namespace and xlink:href is in the xlink namespace.

Use setAttributeNS instead and specify the xlink namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink as the first argument.