# Assigning path in SVG curved text with javascript with xlink:href not working

Tags: javascript, svg, text, dynamic

I've got a tricky problem here, the only answer I've found is here : [Creating Curved Text with SVG and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351886/creating-curved-text-with-svg-and-js)... but when following the solution I still have the same problem : the curved text is not displayed when the tags are generated by code, I guess the curve is not properly assigned to the text through the xlink:href reference.

Here is my sample code : it should display the curved text in all svg tags, but only the debug is working, the dynamic creation and assignation of the href attributes seems to not be working at all.

I can not figure out what's wrong here... :(
Thanks for your help !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        svg{
            border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #337799;">
    <br>
    First test :<br>
    <svg id="original" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400">
        <defs>
            <path id="cuvedPath1" d="M 249.29451409251854 107.29050274981267 A 105 105 0 0 1 298.0259447822062 237.62863470225653"></path>
        </defs>
        <text id="textContainer" fill="white"></text>
    </svg>
    <svg id="debug" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400">

    <br>
    Second test :<br>
    <svg id="original2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400">
        <defs>
            <path id="cuvedPath2" d="M 249.29451409251854 107.29050274981267 A 105 105 0 0 1 298.0259447822062 237.62863470225653"></path>
        </defs>
        <text id="textContainer2" fill="white"></text>
    </svg>
    <svg id="debug2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400">


    </svg>
<script>
    // first test
    var _text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','textpath');
    _text.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','xlink:href','#cuvedPath1');
    _text.textContent = 'my test string';

    _textContainer = document.getElementById('textContainer');
    _textContainer.appendChild(_text);

    // second test
    _text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','textpath');
    _text.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','#cuvedPath2'); // test just with 'href'
    _text.textContent = 'another test string';

    _textContainer = document.getElementById('textContainer2');
    _textContainer.appendChild(_text);

    // debug in another svg tag:
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = document.getElementById('original').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('debug2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('original2').innerHTML;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: textPath, not textpath.

Comment: OMFG Thank you !
Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Robert gave me the right answer: there was a typo in the "textPath" tag which needed an uppercase "P".